# PATCH API with empty request body - AssertionFailedError: expected 204 but was 415

Tags: java, junit, jackson, jax-rs

Our team is developing an API that has a PATCH endpoint with an empty response and an empty request body - the necessary info is carried in the path params. Not my doing, just trying to get tests to run.

When I try to test it, I'm getting 415 response instead of the expected 204. Here's the body of my test:

```
WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(baseUrl).path(path);
// have also tried this:
// WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new JacksonJsonProvider()).target(baseUrl).path(path);

webTarget.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

try {
  final Response response = invocationBuilder.method("PATCH", Entity.json(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Object())));

  assertEquals(204, response.getStatus(), "should return 204 empty response");
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
  fail();
}
```

Interestingly, the following two lines by themselves also return 415 status:

```
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = invocationBuilder.method("PATCH");
```

I see the following error in the console:

```
ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body reader has been found for class java.lang.Object, ContentType: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was the way I defined the endpoint - this annotation caused the problem:

```
@RequestBody() final Object updateRequest
```

Either removing it entirely or changing it to type String got rid of the error.

Obviously I have a lot to learn about jaxrs :-(